# Certifi Path for CA

Tags: python, ssl, certifi

I have python 3.8 installed on my Rhel 7, and when I do a

python3.8 -m certifi

I get the following returned,

/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/certifi/cacert.pem

I need this to be updated so that when I run the command it returns the following path below

/etc/ssl/certs/ca-bundle.crt

Is there any way to achieve this?